# Change SQL Field Data Type varchar to float with data already stored

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter

I have an imported database which contain lots of float field.
When I imported it, all the float field converted to string and I need to convert it back.

I try alter table to change the data type but I keep getting error (even if the row is empty or null).

EDIT : The server is curently down so I can't get the error message at the moment. My DBMS is SQL Server.

Comment: *"but I keep getting error"* - What error? What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do so if all data are really numeric type.
There may be some data which hv null --no problem here.
There may be some data which are blank(('') but not null--problem is because of this.
First you make a select query to retrieve all data which are blank
say,
Select * from table1 where col=''
now update these rows with null
update table1 set col=null where col=''

After this,I think you can easily convert it to float

References: [error converting data type varchar column to float.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1648408.aspx?error%20converting%20data%20type%20varchar%20column%20to%20float%20%22%3Eerror%20converting%20data%20type%20varchar%20column%20to%20float)

Answer (score 0):

You can first add a new field in your table with datatype float and then update it using convert function:

```
UPDATE @tbl
SET
  num = convert(FLOAT, text)

SELECT *
FROM
  @tbl
```

Comment: If he was getting the error converting the column, why wouldn't he get an error creating a new column? Op probably has bad data.